# Conditionally Formatting a Shape's Fill based off of a value in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

I have created a map of a marina in which I have put circle shapes where we have cables that connect the docks. I have these circles hyperlinked to go to a separate sheet with the cable numbers on them. I am supposed to keep track of which cables need maintenance based off of the last date they were worked on. I was wondering if I could conditionally format these circles based off of the date. (Green means good, yellow means within a month, and red means there is a problem.)

Comment: If you're not married to circles this might work for you:  https://www.excelcampus.com/tips/conditional-formatting-shapes/   If not, you can loop through the map sheet's Hyperlinks collection, using each link's SubAddress property to find the linked cable information, check the date, then use the link's `Parent.Name` to identify the shape whose color needs adjusting.

Answer (score 0):

You have not really provided enough details for an exact solution but it is certainly possible to do so.  I have made the following assumption in my code:

- Your marina map is on a worksheet named "Map" (you can change it if it's different)
- Your separate sheet with cable numbers is on a worksheet named "Data" (you can change it if it's different)
- You have a continous range listing all cirle names with their corresponding maintenance dates (you can change the range as well)

[image: Your map with cables ("Point 1", "Point 2" etc]

[image]

Your code which changes shapes' color depending on their last maintenace date:

```
    Dim shp As Shape
    Dim lng As Long
    Dim shtShapes As Worksheet, shtMaintenance As Worksheet
    Dim cll As Range, rngDates As Range, rngPoints As Range
    Dim str As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim dte As Date

    ' Sheet name for the marina map
    Set shtShapes = Sheets("Map")

    ' Sheet name for the maintemance data
    Set shtMaintenance = Sheets("Data")

    ' Range with maintenance data
    Set rngDates = shtMaintenance.Range("B2:B5")
    Set rngPoints = shtMaintenance.Range("A2:A5")
    dte = Now()

    With shtMaintenance
    ' Assign color based on the current date
        For Each cll In rngDates
            Select Case cll.Value - dte
                Case Is > 30: i = 3 'Green
                Case Is > 0: i = 5  'Yellow
                Case Is <= 0: i = 2 'Red
            End Select

    ' Get the corresponding shape name
            str = .Cells(cll.Row, cll.Column - 1).Value

    ' Set the new color
            With shtShapes
                Set shp = .Shapes(str)
                shp.Fill.ForeColor.SchemeColor = i
            End With
        Next
    End With
```

Answer (score 0):

## Shape Fill Changer

[[image] Sheet1:The Map (Liverpool)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AwV6T.jpg)

---

The excel formula for cell **E2** is:

```
=D2-TODAY()+C2
```

[[image] Sheet2: The Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8M3Ls.jpg)

---

> Before using this code carefully study the **constants** section to
>   modify it to fit your needs. Paste it in a module and additionally add
>   the code below appropriately.
>
> The shape names are tied to the Cable IDs and consist of the Shapes
>   Core Name "Cable" and the Cable ID e.g. if the Cable ID is 7 then the
>   shape is named "Cable7".

The code is written so that if you change the headers CABLE ID or the DUE DAYS in the Data Sheet you have to change it in the constants section, too. On the other hand you can insert new columns and regroup columns and the code will still work.

```
Option Explicit

Sub ShapeFillChanger()

  Const cStrCableId As String = "CABLE ID"    ' Cable ID Column Header
  Const cStrDaysData As String = "DUE DAYS"   ' Days Data Column Header
  Const cStrMap As String = "Sheet1"          ' Map Worksheet Name
  Const cStrData As String = "Sheet2"         ' Data Worksheet Name
  Const cStrShape As String = "Cable"         ' Shapes Core Name

  Dim objCableFirst As Range  ' Cable Number First Cell (incl. Header)
  Dim objCableLast As Range   ' Cable Number Last Cell
  Dim objDays As Range        ' Days Range
  Dim objCell As Range        ' Each Cell in Days Range

  Dim lngRGB As Long          ' RGB Color Value
  Dim intDays As Integer      ' Days Column Number

  ' Process worksheet containing data (Data Worksheet).
  With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cStrData)

    ' Find first cell containing cStrCableId.
    Set objCableFirst = .Cells _
        .Find(What:=cStrCableId, After:=.Cells(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count), _
        LookIn:=xlFormulas, Lookat:=xlWhole, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext)

    ' Find last cell containing data in column where cStrCableId was found.
    Set objCableLast = .Range(.Cells(1, objCableFirst.Column), _
        .Cells(.Rows.Count, objCableFirst.Column)) _
        .Find(What:="*", After:=.Cells(1, objCableFirst.Column), _
        LookIn:=xlFormulas, Lookat:=xlWhole, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)

    ' Find first column containing cStrDaysData in row where cStrCabelId was
    ' found.
    intDays = .Range(.Cells(objCableFirst.Row, 1), _
        .Cells(objCableFirst.Row, .Columns.Count)) _
        .Find(What:=cStrDaysData, _
        After:=.Cells(objCableFirst.Row, .Columns.Count), _
        LookIn:=xlFormulas, Lookat:=xlWhole, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext).Column

    ' Create reference to the range of Days Data (Days Range).
    Set objDays = .Range(.Cells(objCableFirst.Row + 1, intDays), _
        .Cells(objCableLast.Row, intDays)) ' " + 1" to exclude Header.

    ' Check each cell value in Days Range and apply changes to Map Worksheet.
    For Each objCell In objDays
      Select Case objCell.Value
        Case Is <= 0  ' Red:    SchemeColor = 2, RGB (255, 0, 0)
          lngRGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        Case Is <= 30 ' Yellow: SchemeColor = 5, RGB (255, 255, 0)
          lngRGB = RGB(255, 255, 0)
        Case Is > 30  ' Green:  SchemeColor = 3, RGB (0, 255, 0)
          lngRGB = RGB(0, 255, 0)
        Case Else
      End Select
      With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cStrMap).Shapes(cStrShape & _
          .Cells(objCell.Row, objCableFirst.Column))
        .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = lngRGB
      End With
    Next

  End With

End Sub
```

> To automatically run the above code every time there was a change on
>   the Data Sheet, in VBE add the following code to the worksheet
>   '**Sheet2**' code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
  ShapeFillChanger
End Sub
```

When ever the Data Sheet is calculated the colors on the Map Sheet will be updated.

Since I figured that the map is the show runner, I put it in worksheet "Sheet1".